# Implement MaxEncodedLen for Nested Origin

Tags: pallet, scale-codec

[orml-authority](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/master/authority/src/lib.rs) implements a mechanism to allow origin to dispatch calls after and only after a delay. This is implemented using a pallet origin [`DelayedOrigin`](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/blob/740f0b83f23f13dc540a8df2773b119446392c57/authority/src/lib.rs#L49).

The `DealyedOrigin` references the original origin so it can dispatch the call with the original origin later after the delay.

Something like:

```rs
enum RuntimeOrigin {
    System(frame_system::Origin),
    OtherPallet(other_pallet::Origin),
    Authority(orml_authoirty::DelayedOrigin<BlockNumber, RuntimeOrigin>),
}

struct DelayedOrigin<BlockNumber, RuntimeOrigin> {
    pub delay: BlockNumber,
    pub origin: Box<PalletsOrigin>,
}
```

With recent version of Substrate, it is required every storage item to have `MaxEncodedLen`.

The default implementation is something like:

```rs
impl MaxEncodedLen for RuntimeOrigin {
    fn max_encoded_len() -> usize {
        1 + max(
          frame_system::Origin::max_encoded_len(),
          other_pallet::Origin::max_encoded_len(),
          PalletsOrigin::<BlockNumber, RuntimeOrigin>::max_encoded_len()
        )
    }
}

impl <BlockNumber, RuntimeOrigin> MaxEncodedLen for DelayedOrigin<BlockNumber, RuntimeOrigin> {
    fn max_encoded_len() -> usize {
        BlockNumber::max_encoded_len() + RuntimeOrigin::max_encoded_len()
    }
}
```

As you can see, we have an infinite recursion here. Mostly because it is possible to construct an instance that is:

```rs
RuntimeOrigin::Authority(DelayedOrigin {
  delay: 0,
  origin: RuntimeOrigin::Authority(DelayedOrigin {
    delay: 0,
    origin: // keep nesting as much as we need
  })
})
```

Therefore the max encoded len is infinite or memory limit.

This wasn't an issue previously because the memory usage is O(n) to the tx size. As long as there is a reasonable tx byte fee, it is ok to nest as many as people wants.

However with recent Weight V2 change, we are required to know the upper size limit of a type. This requirements breaks the current working code.

It is not unreasonable to not support nested `DelayedOrigin` and therefore break the loop. However implementation wise I don't see an easy way.

The code will be something like:

```rs
impl MaxEncodedLen for RuntimeOrigin {
    fn max_encoded_len() -> usize {
        1 + max(
          frame_system::Origin::max_encoded_len(),
          other_pallet::Origin::max_encoded_len(),
          PalletsOrigin::<BlockNumber, RuntimeOrigin>::max_encoded_len()
        )
    }
}

impl RuntimeOrigin {
    fn max_encoded_len_except_authority() -> usize {
        1 + max(
          frame_system::Origin::max_encoded_len(),
          other_pallet::Origin::max_encoded_len(),
        )
    }
}

impl <BlockNumber, RuntimeOrigin> MaxEncodedLen for DelayedOrigin<BlockNumber, RuntimeOrigin> {
    fn max_encoded_len() -> usize {
        BlockNumber::max_encoded_len() + RuntimeOrigin::max_encoded_len_except_authority()
    }
}

impl<BlockNumber, PalletsOrigin> Decode for DelayedOrigin<BlockNumber, PalletsOrigin> {
    fn decode<I: codec::Input>(input: &mut I) -> Result<Self, codec::Error> {
        let delay = Decode::decode(input)?;
        let origin = Decode::decode(input)?;
        require_no_nesting(origin)?;
        Ok(DelayedOrigin { delay, origin })
    }
}
```

However, it is not currently possible to implement `max_encoded_len_except_authority` without modify the `construct_runtime` and it is simply no way to have the `construct_runtime` know what origin may contain nesting.

Also for `require_no_nesting`, there is also no easy way to implement it. One possible implementation is use global variable to assert no reentrancy. But it will be great if there is a more clean way.

---

Side question: What will go wrong if `max_encoded_len` is underestimating the number? i.e. when it returns 200 but the actual answer is max tx length.

Answer (score 3):

You're right that this kind of construct is not directly supported by `MaxEncodedLen` because, just like `Vec<u8>`, it has no strict limit to the encoded length.

I wouldn't really trying to work around the `MaxEncodedLen` trait in this way as you're essentially undermining the protection given by the type system.

One possible direction is to adapt the existing macros to allow your runtime to declare a second `RuntimeOrigin` type called e.g. `NonDelayedRuntimeOrigin`. This would not contain the problematic `DelayedOrigin` variant. You can then have `DelayedOrigin` take an inner type of `NonDelayedRuntimeOrigin`, and you avoid the recursion completely.

> What will go wrong if max_encoded_len is underestimating the number? i.e. when it returns 200 but the actual answer is max tx length.

Essentially the same thing as if the compute-time `Weight` component is under-estimated: Worst case it will lead to a block whose PoV size is necessarily greater than the maximum valid PoV for a block, which will brick the chain.

Comment: that will require some kind of plugin extension to the construct_runtime macro to allow us write some code to generate `NonDelayedRuntimeOrigin`?

Comment: or perhaps just some sort of option to generate a second `Origin` type which skips some of the variants.

Comment: Not very sure how will that to be implemented. Are you suggesting to add some optional parameters to the `construct_runtime` macro to achieve this?

Comment: Yes; that would seem most efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the way using global variable to assert no reentrancy.

https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/pull/845

```rs
impl<BlockNumber: Decode, PalletsOrigin: Decode> Decode for DelayedOrigin<BlockNumber, PalletsOrigin> {
    fn decode<I: codec::Input>(input: &mut I) -> Result<Self, codec::Error> {
        if helper::nested_decode() {
            return Err("Nested DelayedOrigin::decode is not allowed".into());
        }

        helper::set_nested_decode(true);
        defer!(helper::set_nested_decode(false));

        Ok(DelayedOrigin {
            delay: Decode::decode(input)?,
            origin: Decode::decode(input)?,
        })
    }
}

impl<BlockNumber: MaxEncodedLen, PalletsOrigin: MaxEncodedLen> MaxEncodedLen
    for DelayedOrigin<BlockNumber, PalletsOrigin>
{
    fn max_encoded_len() -> usize {
        if helper::nested_max_encoded_len() {
            return 0;
        }

        helper::set_nested_max_encoded_len(true);
        defer!(helper::set_nested_max_encoded_len(false));

        BlockNumber::max_encoded_len() + PalletsOrigin::max_encoded_len()
    }
}
```

This prevents user from submitting tx containing Orign with nested DealyedOrigin and make the `max_encoded_len` return 0 on the reentrancy call, which is fine because it shouldn't be possible to have nesting.

Comment: I tried to use const generics to attach a `nested` level to the Origin such that only a specific nesting limit is reachable, but Rust the features are not yet stable and it also did not work. A macro could be used to define limited nested types.